# Запросы страницы в неправильной кодировке

Tags: yii, кодировка

Проблема следующая: есть сайт на Yii, на котором есть страницы с русскими символами в URL ( http://example.com/Русский_текст). Вижу следующего типа ошибки при логгировании:

```
2013/04/30 12:02:27 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Невозможно обработать запрос "Ð£Ñ Ð¿ÐµÑˆÐ½Ð°Ð¯_ÐœÐ¾Ð´Ð½Ñ ÑˆÐºÐ ".' in /web/CWebApplication.php:286

Stack trace:
#0 /web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('???????????????...')
#1 /base/CApplication.php(169): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#2 /www/example.com/index.php(36): CApplication->run()
#3 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/%C3%90%C2%A3%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%BF%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%91%CB%86%C3%90%C2%BD%C3%90%C2%B0%C3%90%C2%AF_%C3%90%C5%93%C3%90%C2%BE%C3%90%C2%B4%C3%90%C2%BD%C3%91%C2%8F%C3%91%CB%86%C3%90%C2%BA%C3%90%C2%90
---
```

Т.е. получается, что какой то пользователь запрашивает страницу examle.com/Ð£Ñ Ð¿ÐµÑˆÐ½Ð°Ð¯_ÐœÐ¾Ð´Ð½Ñ ÑˆÐºÐ или он запрашивает нормальную страницу, но приложение не понимает  в какой кодировке url

В .htaccess есть AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

В html есть `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Запросы не только к этому адресу бывают с такими ошибками, но и к другим тоже. Проверял у себя через все браузеры, которые у меня есть, все в порядке. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: скниь rules для urlManager

Comment: http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1199

Comment: @do4a 

    'rules'=>array(  'stores/category/<category_name:\w+>'=>'stores/category',
    array('class' => 'application.components.StoreUrlRule',),
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),

Comment: Есть у кого то еще какие то предложения?

Comment: Как вариант, отдавать пользователям URL'ы сразу url-кодированными `<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>`

Comment: кинь контроллер поглядеть еще.

Comment: @Shrek из-за кривого url Yii не понимает, какой контроллер смотреть

Comment: @SergeyTsaplin это не желательно.

Answer (score 2):

Тогда глобальный вопрос! А зачем в URL использовать русский текст?

Тут сразу куча проблем возникает.Зачем делать то что не нужно? пусть все будет в транслите на ENG языке - это проще, привычнее.

А так поехали.

```
http://example.com/Русский_текст
```

Какой контрол по умолчанию стоит? 404 ошибка возникает правильно, он не может найти контроллер на русском языке + и в правилах не прописано <русский язык> => перекинуть на что-то!

Итог простой, сделай правильно описание URL в рулез.

```
'defaultController'=>'stores',
```

в рулез

```
'<category:\w+>'=>'stores/category'
```

ну примерно так.

Comment: в рулез есть строка array('class' => 'application.components.StoreUrlRule',),
Это правило для контроллера Store. Но проблема в том, что когда приходят эти кракозябры, то это правило не подходит и Yii идет дальше по рулезам

Comment: Что там обрабатывается и как?

Вы сами написали, что "Это правило для контроллера Store". Как приложение узнает, что нужен сейчас этот контроллер-то?

Comment: Yii идет по порядку сверху вниз и когда доходит до этого правила, оно возвращает false, а не роут, Yii идет дальше и не находит такой контроллер. Получаю 404

Comment: на eng имена реагирует правильно? Если да, то мой тебе совет, не стоит париться с русским языком, все переведи в транслит!

Comment: @Shrek не получится все перевести, нужны красивые адреса. Вот линк для примера http://buyandsell.com.ua/Сумки_оптом

Comment: Ну можно же не руками переводить, а скриптец написать, обратиться к переводчику гугла или яндекса к их API. и скриптом все разом перевести.

я просто не вижу смысла в русских адресах-это катируется в россии, а в остальном - это понт. Все уже дааавно привыкли к транслитам или полному переводу.